# Is set D together with the following operations a Boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

D = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24}

The question is "Is set D together with the following operations a Boolean algebra?"

The operations are as follows.

1. x + y = lcm(x, y)
2. x . y = gcd(x, y)
3. x' = 24/x

My approach is to prove that set D satisfies the following laws in order to show that it forms a Boolean algebra. The laws are, commutative, distributive, associative, and complement.
I have proven that D follows commutative, distributive, and associative laws.

But I am confused about proving D obeys the complement law. To prove the complement law, We need to prove, x + x' = 1 and x.x' = 0 isn't it? Can anyone help to prove D follows the complement law?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you would have, for example, $4'=24/4=6$, but $\gcd(4,6)=2\neq1$; generally, $D_n$ (the set of divisors of $n$) is a Boolean algebra iff $n$ is square-free. Since $4=2^2$ is a divisor of $24$, $D_{24}$ is not a Boolean algebra.

Comment: Note also, that, in case $D_n$ is a Boolean algebra, then $D_n=\{1,\cdots,n\}$ where $1$ is the $0$ element of this BA (the bottom one) and $n$ is the $1$ element (the top one). I'm adding this because you seem to make that confusion when you claim you should have $x+x'=1$ and $x\cdot x'=0$; in the notation of this example, you need $x+x'=n$ and $x\cdot x'=1$.